# How to solve error regarding that it doesnt open window on Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\lenovo\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-12-02_50.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I get this error, anyone can help?

By the way I installed Kivy library trought PyCharm settings!

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the kivy website for its dependencies?

Comment: Thanks, dependencies was the the thing. I'm good to go now.